# Elapsed days between two dates always giving one days difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to work out the number of days between two dates. Here is how I am doing it:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

unsigned int calendarFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDate *dateToCheck = (self.subscriptionEnd ?: self.trialEnd);
NSLog(@"dateToCheck: %@", dateToCheck);
NSLog(@"current date: %@", [self systemTimeZoneDate]);
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:calendarFlags
                                            fromDate:[self systemTimeZoneDate]
                                              toDate:dateToCheck
                                             options:0];
return [components day] >= 0 ?: 0;
```

At the time of this writing, NSLog outputted the following:

```
2014-09-05 22:56:20.054 tweepy[9635:60b] dateToCheck: 2014-10-05 08:02:51 PM +0000
2014-09-05 22:56:20.057 tweepy[9635:60b] current date: 2014-09-05 10:56:20 PM +0000
```

It is returning a difference of one day because iOS thinks that the day is in YDM format.

Should I be indicating the date format somewhere?

Here is the code of how `self.subscriptionEnd` is setup:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.day = 30;
self.subscriptionEnd = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[self systemTimeZoneDate] options:0];
```

Here is the code of how `self.trialEnd` is setup:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.day = 2;
self.trialEnd = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[self systemTimeZoneDate] options:0];
```

Comment: NSDate doesn't know anything about the "format".  How do you create the NSDates stored in your properties - if you are parsing strings then it definitely cares about formats

Comment: I added new code to my question. Actually I'm more interested in finding how many days.

Comment: If you use NSDateFormatter to parse a string date into NSDate, and don't specify any format, the date format used will be the "default" for your locale.  Further, the date formatter will assume that the date value (unless it carries a timezone designator) is "local time" and will map that to GMT/UTC time in the resulting NSDate object.  Net-net is that you must pay *very careful* attention to date transforming operations.  (Remember, the NSDate object is *always* supposed to contain UTC time.)

Comment: Once you have a date into an NSDate object it has no "format" and it's timezone is fixed as UTC.  You map to the desired timezone and format when you use NSDateFormatter to convert back to string form.

Comment: (But note that NSCalendar *does* have a timezone setting, and you need to consider that when extracting components, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format doesn't have anything to do with it. What is happening is the `NSDateComponents` are giving you what you are asking for, the total difference in years, months, and days. If you want just the days, you need to only provide `NSDayCalendarUnit`. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:) make this clear:

> Some operations can be ambiguous, and the behavior of the computation is calendar-specific, but generally larger components will be computed before smaller components; for example, in the Gregorian calendar a result might be 1 month and 5 days instead of, for example, 0 months and 35 days.

Comment: I did that before and I got the same result: 1 day difference instead of 29 days.

Comment: I just ran the code using NSDayCalendarUnit with the following output:
    dateToCheck: 2014-10-05 22:26:32 +0000
    current date: 2014-09-05 22:43:12 +0000
    <NSDateComponents: 0x8f4dda0>
        Day: 29

Comment: Yeah same here. The first version of my code was fine. It's returning 1 somewhere else :)

Comment: `return [components day] >= 0 ?: 0;` was returning 1 for true. I have rewritten the line as `return [components day] >= 0 ? [components day]: 0;`